# HTML: live calculation via javascript (jquery) including variables with initialization

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, variables, live

i am very new to JS and strugle with the following problem:

I want wo convert the value in the numberbox in the answer beside by any change of the value. Including the variables NP0, NP1 and DP0 from the HTML element.

-------------------------UPDATE 1--------------------------

To use html variables in javascript we can do this via data-* attributes. Thanks to Luca.

But how can I intitiate a calculation, when the page is loading for the first time?

And how can the calculation be executed on any change of the value?

```js
    $(".slide").on('change mousemove', function() { 
      $(this).next(".text").text(this.value)
    });
    $(".calc").on('change paste keyup', function() {  
      $(this).next(".text").text((128+(this.value*0.0625))/1)
    });
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.2.min.js"></script>

<input name="period" class="slide" value="0.25" min="0" max="0.5" step="0.01" style="width: 15em;" type="range"><label class="text">0.25</label>

<br>
<br>
<input name="period" class="calc" value="0" min="0" max="4096" type="number" NP0="128" NP1="0.00625" DP0="1">= <label class="text"></label> km/h
```

Comment: Why are you dividing by 1 in the second to last line of your JavaScript?

Comment: Because the specification dispose this, but this is just an example from a standard.

Comment: call on body load event for first time page loading and $(this).next() is working for you

Comment: @PankajGupta: I tried "<label class="text"><body onload="$(this).previous()"></label> km/h", but there is no output.

Comment: @stahlstngel body on load means  call in body tag ,body tag should be on top

Comment: @stahlstngel i put answer  check this one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need data-* attributes, so your HTML should be

```
<input name="period" class="slide" value="0.25" min="0" max="0.5" step="0.01" style="width: 15em;" type="range"><label class="text">0.25</label>
<br>
<br>
<input name="period" class="calc" value="0" min="0" max="4096" type="number" data-NP0="128" data-NP1="0.00625" data-DP0="1">= <label class="text"></label> km/h
```

and your script

```
 $(".slide").on('change mousemove', function() { 
      $(this).next(".text").text(this.value)
 });
$(".calc").on('change paste keyup', function() {  
  $(this).next(".text").text(($(this).data("np0")+(this.value*$(this).data("np1")))/$(this).data("dp0"))
});
```

**UPDATE 1**

To compute your value immediately when you subscribe needed events, you can use trigger to force a "change" event, so your script should be

```
  $('.calc').on('change paste keyup', function(){
    $(this).next(".text").text(($(this).data("np0")+(this.value*$(this).data("np1")))/$(this).data("dp0"));
  }).trigger('change');
```

Sorry I miss a point :)
To get continuous compute while spinning with buttons, you can add the "input" event, so your code become

```
  $('.calc').on('change paste keyup input', function(){
    $(this).next(".text").text(($(this).data("np0")+(this.value*$(this).data("np1")))/$(this).data("dp0"));
  }).trigger('change');
```

I updated the fiddle, again

[Here a jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/berets/cvozv388/3/)

Comment: No, the slide value is not needed.

Comment: Great. Thanks, that solves my first problem. How can is initiate the calculation when I load the page? And is there a way to execute the calculation for every change of the value (e.g. when I click and hold the value up butten)?

Comment: Delicious!!! That solves all my problems and work well. Great. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1):

```
     <html>
        <head> 
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.2.min.js">/script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
    function Load(){
            $(document).ready(function(){
                 $(".slide").on('change mousemove', function() {
                 $(this).next(".text").text(this.value);

                 });
                     $(".calc").on('change paste keyup', function() {
                     var value = $('#abc').val();  
                    $(this).next(".text").text((128+ value*0.0625)/1)
                });
            });
}
            </script>
        </head>
        <body onLoad="Load()">
            <input id="period" name="period" class="slide" value="0.25" min="0" max="0.5" step="0.01" style="width: 15em;" type="range">

            <label class="text">0.25</label>        <br><br>

            <input id ="abc" name="period" class="calc" value="0" min="0" max="4096" type="number" NP0="128" NP1="0.00625" DP0="1">= 
            <label class="text"></label> km/h
        </body>
    </html>
```

you can use id and get the value through it will update for hope it will help